# UIActivityViewController icons, any way to assign system icons to use for custom activities?

Tags: cocoa-touch, icons, uiactivityviewcontroller

We created a custom activity for email, to get specific behavior that was not possible with the default action. Works fine, but the icon can only be grayscale apparently. See my temporary icon for email below. Is there any way to assign system icons to use for custom activities? Would be much more user friendly is the icon was the colored Mail icon IMO.

[image]